# Json to Array to XML[Php]

Tags: php, xml, json

I'm trying to convert an `array` to `xml` using a `json` in php

The `json` and `array` work fine but when I try converting the `array` to `xml` I keep getting an error.

```
Call to undefined function array_to_xml()
```

This is the json

```
{"host":"127.0.0.1","username":"root","password":"something","dbname":"something","table":"something"}
```

Json to `array

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('something.json'), true);
$info = array(
$json['host'],
$json['username'],
$json['password'],
$json['dbname'],
);
```

Array to xml

```
simplexml_load_string(array_to_xml($json, new SimpleXMLElement('<connection/>'))->asXML()) or die("can't read");
```

Comment: are you using some library or something there is no builtin php function called `array_to_xml`

Comment: Not really and I see. Well is there a way I could possibly get this done?

Comment: you could try looking at [this page](http://darklaunch.com/2009/05/23/php-xml-encode-using-domdocument-convert-array-to-xml-json-encode) they use the DOM interface to create the xml

Answer (score -1):

Maybe because there is no function called array_to_xml()? You have to define it first.

Comment: It should be a comment, really.

Comment: Sorry, not enough reputation. I wanted to help anyway.